# Hamiltonian graph and 2-connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> A non-complete graph is called 2-connected if it stays connected after removing a vertex (and all edges which are incident to that vertex). Show that a Hamiltonian graph is 2-connected.

I'm having difficulty in proving the above statement. I already found in a lot of places that says that if a graph is Hamiltonian than it is 2-connected. Though, I know that if a graph is 2-connected it doesn't necessarily mean that it is Hamiltonian. For example, I came up with the graph below, which is 2-connected, I mean removing the vertex 3, still leaves the graph connected, but the graph is not Hamiltonian.

[image]

Though, this is not exactly what the problem asks. Any idea how to prove the above statement?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: In a Hamiltonian graph there is a cycle containing all vertices.

Comment: I know this fact, though I'm having difficulties in seeing how this will help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Hamiltonian graph there is a cycle containing all vertices.
When you remove one vertex from this cycle, the remaining graph contains a path with all the remaining vertices. Since a path is connected this proves the claim.

Comment: I can see this using my modified graph. So whichever vertex I remove, I still get a one connected component. Though, what I don't understand is, according to me the problem what's me to prove that *any* Hamiltonian graph is 2-connected, am I wrong? Because, let's say if we get the graph composed of 4 vertices, and which has the form of a square, I can have a cycle by simply going through the path $1-2-3-4-1$, which means it is Hamiltonian. But, if I remove one of the vertexes, I will have a disconnected graph.

Comment: No, if you remove one vertex, you still have a connected graph, e.g. if you remove vertex 3, the remaining graph contains the path $412$ and is still connected.

Answer (score 0):

One of the necessary conditions for any graph G to be Hamiltonian,is that w(G-S)≤|S|,for any subgraph of G
Let's go about this using proof by contradiction by assuming that a Hamiltonian graph is not 2 connected
If this were so then there exists a vertice v such that when v is removed from G,G is no longer connected ,that is G has more than one connected component
This vertice is a subgraph with |S|=1
But since there's more than one connected component in G-S,w(G-S)>1
This violates the necessary condition w(G-S)≤|S|
Thus G has to be 2-connected for the graph to be Hamiltonian